# Problem of type inference and type variance for Reactor/WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactor

Let's say there is an interface and its implement class as:

```java
public interface InterfaceA {}

public class ClassA implements InterfaceA {

    public static Mono<ClassA> getMonoA() {
        return Mono.empty();
    }

}
```

And then, for the method `Mono<InterfaceA> getMonoA()`, the following implementation causes a compile error:

```java
Mono<InterfaceA> getMonoA() {
    return ClassA.getMonoA();
}
```

It makes sense that the invariance type `Mono<InterfaceA>` is not the super class of `Mono<ClassA>` even if `InterfaceA` is the super class of `ClassA` and therefore the return type of `ClassA.getMonoA()` which is `Mono<ClassA>` does not match the `Mono<InterfaceA>`.

However, the following implementation works properly:

```java
Mono<InterfaceA> getMonoA() {
    return Mono.just(new ClassA());
}
```

The `Mono.just` method is acturally defined as `public static <T> Mono<T> just(T data)`. As the geneic type `T` in my case is `ClassA`, the method should return the type of `Mono<ClassA>` which should also raise a compile error in my mind.

May I know if there are some mechanisms let `Mono.just` method returns `Mono<InterfaceA>` instead of `Mono<ClassA>` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way how java generics works. In the second example java compiler could infer type. This is the same as defining

```
Mono<InterfaceA> getMonoA() {
   return Mono.<InterfaceA>just(new ClassA());
}
```

But in the first example compiler could not cast `Mono<ClassA>` to `Mono<InterfaceA>` automatically but you could cast it by apply a map function

```
Mono<InterfaceA> getMonoA() {
     return ClassA.getMonoA1().map(Function.identity());
}
```

that is the same as defining `.<InterfaceA>map(c -> c)` or `.map(c -> (InterfaceA) c)`.

or you could define your method as

```
public static <T extends InterfaceA> Mono<T> getMonoA() {
    return ClassA.getMonoA();
}
```

similar how `Mono.just` is defined.

Due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), both `Mono<InterfaceA>` and `Mono<ClassA>` will be `Mono` during runtime, so there will be no real type check regarding the element type. You could use unsafe cast that will work in this case but potentially could result in `ClassCastException` when you try to access the object

```
Mono<InterfaceA> getMonoA() {
    return (Mono) ClassA.getMonoA();
}
```

It's not something specific to Reactor or WebFlux. The same is valid for any generic types. For example, `List<InterfaceA>` vs `List<ClassA>`.

Comment: Therefore, it means that the compiler can infer generic type `Mono<T>` to `Mono<InterfaceA>`  even if the real type of `T` is `ClassA` which is an implementation of `InterfaceA`. On the other side, the non-generic type `Mono<ClassA>` can not be inferred to `Mono<InterfaceA>`.

Comment: Updated the answer. Due to type erasure, both `Mono<InterfaceA>` and `Mono<ClassA>` will be Mono during runtime, so there will be no real type check regarding the element type. You could use unsafe cast `(Mono) ClassA.getMonoA()` that will work in this case.

Comment: It's not something specific to Reactor or WebFlux. The same is valid for any generic type. For example, `List<InterfaceA>` vs `List<ClassA>`

Answer (score 1):

I think one way to look at this is the question how the type `T` is interpreted by the compiler. If you define

```
interface InterfaceB {
}

static class ClassB implements InterfaceB {
}
```

then the following will not compile (as expected)

```
    Mono<InterfaceA> getMonoTest() {
    return Mono.just(new ClassB());     
    }
```

with the message similar to this one

> type mismatch: cannot convert from Mono<ClassB> to Mono<InterfaceA>

So the compiler does check if the type `T` corresponds to the return type of the method. `MonoJust` is [defined](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/3723e9d5ab25318d28818ecb52a097a4937350fb/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/MonoJust.java#L28) as a generic Publisher and you are returning `MonoJust<InterfaceA>` not `MonoJust<ClassA>`.

```
final class MonoJust<T> extends Mono<T> ...

final T value;
MonoJust(T value) {
    this.value = Objects.requireNonNull(value, "value");
}
```

On the other hand, `MonoEmpty`is [defined](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/3723e9d5ab25318d28818ecb52a097a4937350fb/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/MonoEmpty.java#L34) as a `Publisher<Object>`:

```
final class MonoEmpty extends Mono<Object> ....

static final Publisher<Object> INSTANCE = new MonoEmpty();

MonoEmpty() {
    // deliberately no op
}
```

and you would have to define type boundaries:

```
Mono<? extends InterfaceA> getMonoA()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But I'm afraid the problem has nothing to do with the `Mono.empty()` method, because it can return either `Mono<InterfaceA>` or `Mono<ClassA>` just according to the return type of  `getMonoA` in `ClassA` class. I totally agree with you that the question is related to how the compiler interprets the generic type, and it is really what I want to know in my question.

Comment: I think Alex' answer makes a point in the direction you are looking for with the type erasure. Wrapping `return Mono.just(new ClassA());` in a method with the return type `Mono<ClassA>` yields the same error. There were changes between Java 7 & Java 8 regarding the `Target Types` inference (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) so it might evolve with time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reference. I think I can get the point now.

Comment: Glad to help, Java generics is always a nice topic :)